# Trying to access and print the values from the fields within Paragraph

Tags: theming, paragraphs

I'm having trouble trying to access and print the values manually within the Paragraph. This is a snippet from the paragraph field template I have created. I wanted to access and print values manually instead of Drupal generating the markup using `{{ slides.content }}` so that I could customize the markup myself

```
{% for slides in items %}
    {{ slides.content['#options'].entity.field_label.value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Customize the markup by providing twig templates for the fields within the paragraph. Then no complex loops are really needed.

Comment: Aside from that is there anyway to access it directly instead of having to create multiple field twig templates?

Comment: This looks like the standard loop of a field template, only that `item` was renamed to `slides`. Then `slides.content` contains the output of a field formatter configured by you in Manage Display of the paragraph type.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what worked for me to manually get parts of a field in a paragraph template.

This is in a field template for the actual paragraph, so for me `field--field-paragraph.html.twig`. I have an image field with the machine name `field_image`. This prints just the alt text of that image.

```
{% for item in items %}
  {{ item.content['#paragraph'].field_image.0.alt }}
{% endfor %}
```

I looked here for working with paragraph templates: https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs/issues/2662766#comment-12528934 and here for general drupal 8 field-getting: https://blog.usejournal.com/getting-drupal-8-field-values-in-twig-22b80cb609bd

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend not to use field templates for things like this, but use an entity template (like `paragraph--BUNDLETYPE.html.twig`) instead.

In an entity template you can access the rendered HTML output of any sub-field like `{{ content.field_whatever }}`, but you can also access raw field values for stuff like `{% if paragraph.field_whatever.value == 'foo' %}`